# Byte-addressed memory (Data alignment)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, data-structures, x86

**I don't want you to do my homework. I just want some tips on how to do that so I can learn it myself.**

Given is a byte-addressed memory which writes from the lowest to the highest addresses. Then I have a C program which has the following declarations:

```
long int i = 1;
char c = 'x';
short int n = 10;
short in m = 11;
float f = 0.0;
```

In IA32 Int is 4 bytes, char is 1 byte, short is 2 byte and float is 4 byte. How will these declaration be saved in the memory most likely? Fill out the following in hex digits.

[image]

How do I begin here? Can you give me some tips? What's the first thing I have to do?

**EDIT: MY PROF TOLD ME THAT THE SYSTEM IS IA32.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your variables are declared and defined as local (not static/global) variables, for example:

```
int main()
{
    long int i = 1;
    char c = 'x';
    short int n = 10;
    short in m = 11;
    float f = 0.0;
}
```

If so, they are allocated on the stack.

The principles of allocating local variables on stack are roughly the same for all systems:

1. Stack grows from high addresses to low addresses
2. The order of declaration of your variables in your program corresponds to growth of stack
3. Each type has alignment - the address of any variable must be divisible by its size (1 for `char`, 2 for `short`, etc)
4. Try to waste as little space as possible

There is a conflict between principles (2) and (4) - if rearranging variables saves space, will the compiler do it? I guess you can assume NO (this is the "most likely" part in your question).

The real situation is much more complicated than this (`sizeof` is not really prescribed by the above numbers; alignment requirement is not always equal to `sizeof`; compiler may reuse space for two different variables; etc) - but you have to simplify it if you want to solve your homework in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: The C standard does not even require to use a stack. And stacks do not necesarily descend. The question does not even mention it would be a stack 3) is wrong. There are larger and smaller alignments for other than `char` types (only `char` is defined) in existing architectures. The compiler must **not** reorder struct fields, local variables can easily be held in registers, globals also have some restrictions, etc.

Comment: I agree with that. That's why I wrote the last paragraph in my answer. All the info you provide is true, and I could put it there, but you really don't want to throw several multi-megabyte ABI manuals at the OP just to answer a simple question, right? IMO a short "it's complicated" disclaimer at the end is enough, and I already got carried away with 3 ways it could get complicated.

Comment: OP has to provide a specific layout, so he **does** need a specific ABI (they are not **that** big or complicated for C actually). Your ciams do not hold, however, You start with preconditions you do not explain, but atate as given, allthough they are not (e.g.: where does OP state these are local variables?, they use a stack, the stack is descending, ... ). Just a "it is complicated" is not sufficient. Sometimes no answer is better than a missleading answer. In that respect, the comments on the question are much more helpful than your answer.

Comment: Note I did not DV, yetr, because it is a kind of answer which just uses implicit constraints. My criticism is the constraints are nowhere explained respectively relativated.

Comment: @Olaf A great point on the assumption of stack, which is in fact unwarranted! I clarified that I assumed it.

Comment: You missed the actual point: even for local variables, there is no requirement to use a stack. Even if, that is not necessarily descending (there are architectures with an ascending stack).

Answer (score 3):

> just want some tips on how to do that so I can learn it myself.

1. Write a program implementing the definitions in question.
2. Compile it using symbols.
3. Run it in a debugger and inspect the addresses of the variables in question.

As an alternative to step 2. and 3. above, you could just print out the addresses using:

```
printf("myvar's address=%p", (void*) &myvar);
```

Comment: In my exams in February I'm not allowed to use any computer, just my brain and a paper. How do I solve that then?

Comment: @S.Eberl Learn/practice the alignment rules for all systems in scope for your exam.

Comment: @S.Eberl:L You can try to have the exam invalidated if it does not give the information necessary. Alternatively, you can learn for a specific implementation and state that in your answer, supplying the missing information and criticise the question as given. It is objectively unsolvable without additional constraints.

Comment: @S.Eberl: Regarding your edit stating IA32 to be the target platform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#x86 Please note that C implementations do **not** necessarily need to stick to the integers sizes mentioned in the link above, but still are free to chose their integer's sizes inside the ranges given by the C Standard (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20)